# Facebook conversion pixel with "server to server" option

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm investigating usage of CPA ad types in our application and was reading about pixels for tracking conversions. It states that there are JS/HTML pixels available, but I'm wondering if there is a pixel that could be triggered on server side, (i.e. using `file_open` from our script). This would be a huge benefit for my app, since it would enable me to lower discrepancy and also allow more flexibility.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no ability to record conversion using a server-to-server method at the moment.

Comment: Now you can use Offline Conversions api. Look at the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43974742/834003

Answer (score 1):

**Now you have options for behavior like this.** Note: You cannot fire a "piexl" from the server, because pixels are specific to web pages.

Facebook created the [Offline Conversions api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions/v2.9) to allow you to upload conversions that happen outside a website, like users purchasing something in a brick and mortar, or conversions that don't count until you have verified the information yourself (i.e. you must have a human review a user's sign up)

Answer (score 0):

Now the right way to do it is using the [Conversions API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api):

> The Conversions API allows advertisers to send web events from their servers directly to Facebook. Server events are linked to a pixel and are processed like browser pixel events.

So it's exactly what you need.

(It's previously called Facebook Server-Side API, by the way.)